# Angular issue displaying subitems with ngFor

Tags: angular, angular11

I have some data which I need to display in the component html and consists of folder names and the files inside the folders.

Here is the data:

```
data = [
    {
      "name": "folder1", 
      "files": [ 
        { 
          "name": "file1.txt", 
        },
        { 
          "name": "file2.txt", 
        }  
      ] 
    },
    { 
      "name": "folder2", 
      "files": [ 
        { 
          "name": "file1.txt", 
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "file2.txt", 
        },
        { 
          "name": "file3.txt", 
        } 
      ] 
    }
    
  ];
```

And this is what I'm trying:

```
<ul *ngFor="let test of data">
  <li><h5>{{ test.name }}</h5></li>
  <li>{{ test.files.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

But the result I'm getting is:

```
folder1
folder2
folder1
folder2
folder1
folder2
```

The output I need is:

```
folder1
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
folder2
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
  file3.txt
```

How can I fix this so it displays correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how that code is producing exactly that output - are you sure it's the real code? `{{ test.files.name }}` would be null, from your example.

Anyway, you are only looping through the folders - to list the content, you need an inner loop for the files. So you can just nest it - something like this.

```
<ul *ngFor="let test of data">
  <li><h5>{{ test.name }}</h5></li>
  <ul *ngFor="let file of test.files">
    <li>{{ file.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Note - this is only to show the idea - in reality this would cause a problem if any folder doesn't have a files property, so some checks would be a good idea.